# Google Drive file picker wanted - but get a local file picker

Tags: java, android, google-drive-picker

I want to open a File Picker to selecting Folders in Google Drive. But my File Picker only shows local folders.

Connection to Google Drive is successfully established. I query the root folder of Google Drive and want do open the File Picker on root level immediately after this query.

In my GoogleDriver.class I call the picker like:

```
Activity.getInstance().openFilePicker(mDriveServiceHelper);
```

From this `Activity` I call:

```
public void openFilePicker(DriveServiceHelper mDriveServiceHelper) {
    if (mDriveServiceHelper != null) {
        Intent pickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        pickerIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);          
        startActivityForResult(pickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    }
}
```

`IntentFilter` in `manifest`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Thanks for supporting me
Alejandro

Now the picker opens, but not in Google Drive, it opens locally.

Comment: Of course. There is nothing in the intent that has anything to do with google drive to begin with. Or with opening in a certain folder.

Comment: Further it is unclear what you want with your intent filter. And you did not post code handling such an intent.

Comment: what I have to change, to get content of google drive?

Comment: You can not select a folder from Google drive using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. You can only select a file from Google drive using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: OK, thank you. Since I want to give users the option to choose the folder themselves, I guess I'll have to build it myself

Comment: If Google drive does not give you uries for folders then why do you think you can build up an uri for a folder. An uri that would be accepted by Google drive?

Comment: I will query Google Drive with api v3 and work with IDs

Comment: I query all folders that contain the desired files. I would have preferred to let this do by the user, as this would be more logical in the process.